# Using radio buttons to change a calculation

Tags: r, radio-button, shiny

I want to use radio buttons (input$relStat) so each option runs a different calculation for `textOutput`. The inputs come from a slider for `basicIncome` and numeric for `childNum`.

`ui.R`

```
sliderInput(inputId = "basicIncome", 
              label = "Choose a monthly basic income", 
              value = 600, min = 0, max = 1200, step = 50
  ),

textOutput("annualBasicIncome"),
)
```

`server.R`

```
annualBasicIncome <- eventReactive(input$updateButton, {
  if ("1" %in% input$relStat)
    renderText({(input$basicIncome*12)+((input$basicIncome*12)*input$childNum)})

  if ("2" %in% input$relStat)
    renderText({(2*(input$basicIncome*12))+((input$basicIncome*12)*input$childNum)})
})

output$annualBasicIncome <- renderText({
  annualBasicIncome()
})
```

I've tried to give the radioButton into a value. But binary.

If I remove the first `if("1")` then for one radioButton option nothing is displayed and for the other I get the error `argument 1 (type 'closure') cannot be handled by 'cat'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
switch(as.numeric(input$relStat),
  return((input$basicIncome*12)+((input$basicIncome*12)*input$childNum)),
  return((2*(input$basicIncome*12))+((input$basicIncome*12)*input$childNum))
)
```

That should get you the result you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm still floundering though. Could you tell me whereabouts this chunk is meant to go? I've tried saving relStat$Input in a similar way to example 2 [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/basics.html) to no avail. '

Comment: @gizzard, try the switch instead of your if statements (as edited). You can see that I used `return` because then `annualBasicIncome()` will get the value you want to show. Then the function you wrote should print it, but if it doesn't work, try using `verbatimTextOutput` instead `textOutput` and `renderPrint` instead of `renderText`. Cheers.